# How to get all references of Enum.name() of a specific enum?

Tags: java, enums

I have a java enum `State` that inherits the method 
[java.lang.Enum.name()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/Enum.html#name()).

In Eclipse, I would like to find all uses of the `name()` method of my specific `State` enum (so I *don't want* to get uses of others enum's `name()` method).

How could I do that ? (if this is even possible)

Comment: Please paste what you've tried.

Comment: @NicholasK: I think this is an IDE feature question, not a code question.